# django require_http_methods. default page

Tags: python, django

I use require_http_methods for restricting access to views. Here example my code:

```
# myapp/views.py
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('my_view')
```

But when I go to url `/myapp/my_view` I see white page. So, my question is: How I can set default view if method not match rules? For example I want to show 404, 403 or something else. It is possible? Can you provide me a small example? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case 405 HTTP error is returned.

You could try to create [`middleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/) for custom errors:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseNotAllowed


class CustomHTTPErrorsMiddleware(object):

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if isinstance(response, HttpResponseNotAllowed):
            # Custom response for `HttpResponseNotAllowed`.
            pass
        return response
```

Also, Django's [error handling](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#error-handling) may be useful.