# How do I redirect from require_http_methods without using middleware?

Tags: django, django-views

I used a `@require_http_methods` decorator in my code for the *logout* page, but I can't wrap my head around the proper way to redirect a user on the method error.

It is suggested to create a middleware there: [django require_http_methods. default page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474466/django-require-http-methods-default-page)

But I wonder if there is a simpler way?

---

(I know I can just check for a method manually like this: `if method == 'POST'`) But I want to know what the best practice is.

Comment: Exactly to what it should redirect?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem To any page I specify (website index perhaps)

Thank you for your answer, it's very useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom decorator based on the [**`@require_http_methods`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_http_methods) by altering its [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/views/decorators/http.py#L18-L42), such that it redirects instead of returning a HTTP 405 error:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def require_http_methods_redirect(request_method_list, redirect_to=None):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.method not in request_method_list:
                if redirect_to is not None:
                    return redirect(redirect_to)
                else:
                    response = HttpResponseNotAllowed(request_method_list)
                log_response(
                    'Method Not Allowed (%s): %s', request.method, request.path,
                    response=response,
                    request=request,
                )
                return response
            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return inner
    return decorator
```

then in your logout view, you can specify a `redirect_to`:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

@require_http_methods_redirect(['POST'], redirect_to=reverse_lazy('name-of-some-view'))
def my_view(request):
    # …
```